# Reading a PSEye Camera frame

Tags: c++, camera

I am using the CL Eye Multicam C++ API to obtain frames from a PSEye camera and I found something interesting I hope someone can explain to me this behaviour.

Following [this example](http://codelaboratories.com/research/view/cl-eye-platform-cpp-sample) if I use the regular code (around line 108) :

```
while(_running)
{
    cvGetImageRawData(pCapImage, &pCapBuffer);
    CLEyeCameraGetFrame(_cam, pCapBuffer);
    cvShowImage(_windowName, pCapImage);
}
```

The pCapBuffer is updated, BUT if I just do:

```
while(_running)
{    
    CLEyeCameraGetFrame(_cam, pCapBuffer);     
}
```

`pCapBuffer` remais `NULL`! So for what I see `CLEyeCameraGetFrame()` just updates `pCapBuffer` when someone "consumes" it...what I don't get is how does `CLEyeCameraGetFrame()` knows that the buffer was read? I was expecting the `pCapBuffer` to be updated everytime I called `CLEyeCameraGetFrame()`....is this the regular behaviour in camera frame reads?

Also if someone could point me out how to make a `QImage` out of this `pCapBuffer` it will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood what's going on...`cvGetImageRawData()` copies the image `pCapImage` raw data to `pCapBuffer` and thus gives it an address, making it point to the image class internal data representation. So everytime `CLEyeCameraGetFrame()` is called it changes the data inside `pCapBuffer`, which is the same data inside `pCapImage`. The designer of this code simply used the OpenCV functions to initialize a buffer with the right amount of space and used it to acquire the frame image.